# Augmented Matrix - Vertical line has absurd thinkness

Tags: matrices, arrays

So i used this code to generate an augmented matrix.

```
\[
\left[A | b\right] =
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
    1 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
    2 & 2 & 2 & 2
\end{array}\right]
\]
```

But, it seems to be producing this:

[image]

Any suggestions so as to how I can fix that absurdly thick line. Also, the symbol `|` seems to be showing the normal behavior when it is used outside matrices.

**Edit:** Found the problem `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}` seemed to be doing this. Thanks to @percusse for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: something else in your document should be causing this

Comment: Found it, apparantly this was causing the issue. Thank you. `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to the OP using a setting that wasn't reported in the question